# WCF and ASP.Net Precompile

Tags: asp.net, wcf, precompile

Have a WCF service in a "Services" directory in my asp.net web app. In

```
/Services/MyService.svc
/Services/MyService.svc.cs
```

Everything works when copying my source code to the virtual directory. We were really hoping to precompile the code for various reasons, but when we do the service breaks. I am assuming becuase now the ".cs" file is precompiled and there no longer is a "MyService.svc.cs" in the "/Services" directory.

**The Error**

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://myurl.com/services/MyService.svc

**My .svc mark up is the standard:**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MyNamespace.MyService" CodeBehind="MyNamespace.MyService.svc.cs" %>
```

**Is there something I am doin wrong, or that I can change on the WCF client/service to allow for ASP.net precomilation?**

Comment: is it a web site or web application?

Comment: @BrandonZeider - Its a web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about a precompiled site, take a look at [this blog post](http://nimtug.org/blogs/damien-mcgivern/archive/2008/01/30/wcf-required-precompiled-asp-net-site-to-be-updatable.aspx). Basically the site has to be updatable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but we wanted didn't want the site to be "updatable" which is one of the reasons we want to precompile.

Comment: @AGoodDisplayName - There were some comments at that link that suggested some other options. Check those out. :)

Comment: @tridus - thanks you are right The suggestions do have the answer we found to work. I am going to accept this answer, see my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

One of my coworkers found this and it works. It is not the best solution, but it works.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/8c897f8e-2143-450e-a9f4-97d1f8702da7/

EDIT:

Even better solution...We use a deployment project and it seems that the project specifies the project name as the virtual directory path unless otherwise specified. We opened up our deployment project file and updated the below node to the appropriate virtual directory name:

```
<SourceWebPhysicalPath>..\MyVirtualDirectory</SourceWebPhysicalPath>
```